# Bootstrap input-group smaller than on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm quite new to the front-end and bootstrap. Usually on the backend. What I'm trying to do is to show an email input with a submit button attached to it.

I used the 'input-group-btn' which did accomplish the purpose (www.conglinwang.com/signup), but the problem is that on mobile devices, the input field and submit button is way smaller than other email input boxes. Can you help advise on how to make it larger?

Code:

```
        <form method='post' class='form-horizontal'>
        <div class="row form-group form-group-lg">
         <div class="input-group col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control email_input" id="reserve_email_1" placeholder="QQ或邮箱号">
            <span class='input-group-btn'>
            <button type="button" id="subscribe_1" class="btn btn-success subscribe_button">让我试试</button>
            </span>
         </div>

        <div class='input-group col-sm-1'></div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: oddy, when I shrink the browser, elements move into place and it looks pretty usable. but if I actually visit the site on an iPhone, it's the full layout - mostly unreadable and like you say, with too small an input. are you using some browser detector to inhibit bootstrap responsiveness?

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I'm not using any detector except those that might have been implemented by bootstrap itself. I just tested it with an Android phone and things stack on top of each other as. The major problem is that in this layout, the email input and button would still be too small for people to tap on: I had to enlarge it on my screen to actually type into it.

Comment: yeah, I'm sure. _Something_ is keeping phones from actually scaling like bootstrap is meant to do. I think it's not something we see in the code above, but almost certainly therein lies your problem...